# Overflow buffer in C on x86_64 to call function

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

Hello i have such code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SECRET "1234567890AZXCVBNFRT"
int checksecret(){
    char buf[32];
    gets(buf);
    if(strcmp(SECRET,buf)==0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void outsecret(){
    printf("%s\n",SECRET);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if (checksecret()){
        outsecret();
    };
}
```

disass of outsecret

```
(gdb) disassemble outsecret 
Dump of assembler code for function outsecret:
   0x00000000004005f4 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x00000000004005f5 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004005f8 <+4>: mov    $0x4006b4,%edi
   0x00000000004005fd <+9>: callq  0x400480 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400602 <+14>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000400603 <+15>:    retq
```

I have an assumption that i don't know `SECRET`, so i try to run my program with such string `python -c 'print "A" * 32 + "\x40\x05\xf4"[::-1]'`. But it fails with segmentation fault. What i am doing wrong? Thank you for any help.

## PS

I want to call function `outsecret` by overwriting return code in `checksecret`

Comment: It's almost as if you cannot count!! Surely you noticed that the string you passed has more characters than allocated in your buffer!

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember that all strings have an extra character that terminates the string, so if you input 32 characters then `gets` will write *33* characters to the buffer. Writing beyond the limits of an array leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which often leads to crashes.

The `gets` function have no bounds-checking, and is very dangerous to use. It has been deprecated since long, and in the latest C11 standard it has even been removed.

Comment: I know it, it is a task to teach howto overwriting return code of the function to make an attack to this program

Comment: @MikeMinaev Well undefined behavior (which is what you're trying to exploit) is by its very definition undefined, you need to be very precise at what you're trying to do. If you make any mistake then all you will get is the crash (or other weird behavior).

Comment: @MikeMinaev Also, the function you should try to exploit is not the `outsecret` function but the `checksecret` function, so that's the function you should look at.

Comment: i am trying to do smth line this. I want to input some string witch will override return code in `checksecret` from place where it was called from main to `outsecret`

Comment: @MikeMinaev: AFAIK integer return value is stored directly in `%eax` register, due to [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) (that's assuming that you have `x86` or `x86-64` CPU). Stack-likely-located array `buf` is handled by `%rbp` offsets within current [stack frame](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ python -c 'print "A" * 32 + "\x40\x05\xf4"[::1]'
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA@

$ perl -le 'print length("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA@")'
33
```

Your input string is too long for buffer size of 32 characters (extra one is needed for `'\0'` terminating *null character*). You are victim to buffer or array overflow (sometimes also called as array overrun).

Note that `gets()` is deprecated in C99 and eventually it [has been dropped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29#Changes_from_C99) in C11 Standard for security reasons.

---

> I want to call function outsecret by overwriting return code in
>   checksecret

Beware, you are about to leave <strike>relatively</strike> safe regions of C Standard. This means that behaviour is relative to compiler, compiler's versions, optimization settings, ABI and so on (maybe inclucing current phase of moon).

[image]

As of [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) integer return value is stored directly in `%eax` register (that's assuming that you have `x86` or `x86-64` CPU). Stack-likely-located array `buf` is handled by `%rbp` offsets within [current stack frame](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/). Let's consult with `gdb` disassemble command:

```
$ gcc -O0 test.c

$ gdb -q a.out
(gdb) b checksecret
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400631 in checksecret ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function checksecret:
   0x000000000040062d <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040062e <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
=> 0x0000000000400631 <+4>: sub    $0x30,%rsp
   0x0000000000400635 <+8>: mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x000000000040063e <+17>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400642 <+21>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400644 <+23>:    lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400648 <+27>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040064b <+30>:    callq  0x400530 <gets@plt>
   0x0000000000400650 <+35>:    lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000400654 <+39>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x0000000000400657 <+42>:    mov    $0x400744,%edi
   0x000000000040065c <+47>:    callq  0x400510 <strcmp@plt>
   0x0000000000400661 <+52>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400663 <+54>:    jne    0x40066c <checksecret+63>
   0x0000000000400665 <+56>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x000000000040066a <+61>:    jmp    0x400671 <checksecret+68>
   0x000000000040066c <+63>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400671 <+68>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
   0x0000000000400675 <+72>:    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
   0x000000000040067e <+81>:    je     0x400685 <checksecret+88>
   0x0000000000400680 <+83>:    callq  0x4004f0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x0000000000400685 <+88>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400686 <+89>:    retq
```

There is no way overwrite `%eax` directly from C code, but what you could do is to overwrite selective fragment of code section. In your case what you want is to replace:

```
0x000000000040066c <+63>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
```

with

```
0x000000000040066c <+63>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
```

It's easy to accomplish by `gdb` itself:

```
(gdb) x/2bx 0x40066c
0x40066c <checksecret+63>:  0xb8    0x00

set {unsigned char}0x40066d = 1
```

Now let's confirm it:

```
(gdb) x/i 0x40066c
   0x40066c <checksecret+63>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
```

From that point `checksecret()` is returning `1` even if `SECRET` does not match. However It wouldn't be so easy to do it by `buf` itself, as you need to know (guess somehow?) correct offset of particular code section instruction.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but in the task said that i must manipulate with input text, not with some registers.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are pretty clear and corret way to exploit buffer overflow vulnerability. But there is a different way to do same thing without exploit vulnerability.

```
mince@rootlab tmp $ gcc test.c -o test
mince@rootlab tmp $ strings test
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc.so.6
gets
puts
__stack_chk_fail
strcmp
__libc_start_main
__gmon_start__
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.2.5
UH-X
UH-X
[]A\A]A^A_
1234567890AZXCVBNFRT
;*3$
```

Please look at last 2 row. You will see your secret key in there.